# Why conda installs old pytorch with by default with cudatoolkit=11.2

Tags: pytorch, conda

I am trying to install `conda` for `cudatoolkit=11.2` on google colab using:

```
conda install pytorch cudatoolkit=11.2 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

But why does it install old `pytorch=1.0.0` version not something `>1.6`?

If I try to force install `pytorch=1.6`, it gives the following error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with a past
explicit spec that is not an explicit spec in this operation (cudatoolkit):

  - cudatoolkit=11.2
  - pytorch=1.6 -> cudatoolkit[version='>=10.1,<10.2|>=10.2,<10.3|>=9.2,<9.3']

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package setuptools conflicts for:
setuptools
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools
conda[version='>=4.10.3'] -> setuptools[version='>=31.0.1']
wheel -> setuptools
pip -> setuptools
...
```

### EDIT based on the answer:

When I try to use `conda install -c conda-forge pytorch cudatoolkit=11.2`, it gives the following error.

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - cudatoolkit=11.2
  - __glibc[version='>=2.17,<3.0.a0']

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

Comment: [This](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#start-locally) might help?

Comment: Can you create a public CoLab notebook with your setup of Conda leading up to this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The **pytorch** channel](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch/files) doesn't yet have any `pytorch` builds compatible with `cudatoolkit=11.2`. What the solver finds is an old version of PyTorch where they did not have proper upper bounds on the dependency version.

If you insist on `cudatoolkit=11.2`, then you'll need to stick to the Conda Forge stack:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge pytorch cudatoolkit=11.2
```

Otherwise, if you want the official PyTorch builds, then they build up to v11.1 compatible versions:

```bash
conda install -c pytorch -c conda-forge pytorch cudatoolkit=11.1
```

Comment: Still gives me error: `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:  - cudatoolkit=11.2`

Comment: @kkgarg you must have something wrong. I just verified both commands work. If using `cudatoolkit=11.2` you must include `-c conda-forge` and not `-c pytorch`.

Comment: Added the error to the question based on your suggestion in the answer, it doesnt solve my problem

Comment: @kkgarg this is very confusing since `conda search -c conda-forge/linux-64 cudatoolkit=11.2` resolves four compatible builds.

Comment: It worked on colab, maybe I was trying the command on some other setup which had maybe different cuda version. But Colab had 11.2 and it worked fine there.